# Key combination doesn't work

Tags: java, swing

I am newbe in Java programming. I want to create a shortcut for the foreign character in my textfield using key combination but it does not work at all.

**Code:**

```
txtFind = new JTextField();
    txtFind.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {




        @Override
        public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent arg0) {
            loadlist();
        }


        public void keyPressed(org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyEvent e) {
            if((e.stateMask == SWT.ALT) && (e.stateMask == SWT.SHIFT) && (e.keyCode == 'a' ))
             {
         txtFind.setText(txtFind.getText() + "Ā"); 
        }
        }
    });
    txtFind.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    txtFind.setBounds(10, 7, 113, 20);
    panelSearch.add(txtFind);
    txtFind.setColumns(10);
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Are you using Swing OR SWT, they are different frameworks

Comment: If you are using Swing, you'd be better of using the Key Bindings API

Comment: Because I am a newbie, that is why I still mix everything. By the way, I want to use Swing as for my experience, it works faster.

Comment: Take a look at [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Swing you compare it like this:

```
if( e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A )
```

Read more here: [How to write a KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

Comment: Generally speaking, it's a bad idea to try and modify a text component from a Key Listener, as the key event can be consumed before your listener is notified and/or generate a modification exception.

Comment: There's more to answer a question then simply solving the "apparent" problem, sometimes, you need to lead the OP to the right answer to solve the problem they are trying to solve - IMHO

Comment: Hi, Murat K, thank you for the help. I can get what I want with the following code: 
if ((evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) && ((evt.getModifiers() & KeyEvent.ALT_MASK ) != 0)) {
               jTextField2.setText(jTextField2.getText() + "ā"); 
            }    

It will produce character ā. But if I use the following code:

if ((evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) && ((evt.getModifiers() & KeyEvent.SHIFT_MASK & KeyEvent.SHIFT_MASK) != 0)) {
               jTextField2.setText(jTextField2.getText() + "Ā"); 
            } 
I will get āĀ. In this case, I only want Ā. How to solve it?

Comment: Since KeyEvent inherits InputEvent you can simply call the method e.isShiftDown() and check for it.

Comment: Still very hard to figure it out. Even with the following code: 

if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A && evt.isAltDown() && evt.isShiftDown()) {
               jTextField2.setText(jTextField2.getText() + "\u0101"); 
            }   
  "\u0101" is Ā but in the text field it produce only ā.

Comment: I figure it out as what I expected:  private void jTextField2KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A && evt.isAltDown() && evt.isShiftDown()) {
               jTextField2.setText(jTextField2.getText() + "\u0100"); 
            }    
else if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A && evt.isAltDown() ) {
               jTextField2.setText(jTextField2.getText() + "\u0101"); 
            }   
    }   
it will produce Ā and ā respectively. Thank you.

Comment: But, why VK_A does not work in Eclipse? It works fine in the NetBeans. Are they using different way of expression?

Comment: Uhm maybe your Eclipse auto-imported a different library as you copy-pasted it over.